# Django REST framework request data

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Im using DJango REST framework to write my web service layer in which I want to read request payload from the request (POST). I tried the following code but I get empty set

```
@api_view(['POST'])
def login(request):
    print request.POST
```

Content Type is JSON. I tried to pass data from REST Client Tool. Still am able to read header values but only Payload is not coming out.

Comment: Can you provide more detail as to how you are sending your POST request? Have you tried debugging to inspect `request`?

Comment: curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '
{
    "name": "siva",
}' http://127.0.0.1:8000/authentication/login

when I print.POST I got "<QueryDict: {}>"

Comment: You may also be running into CSRF issues, are you exempting the view from using csrf?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should use `request.DATA` instead of `request.POST` to retrieve json data.

> `request.DATA` has been deprecated in favor of `request.data` since version 3.0, and has been fully removed as of version 3.2.

Comment: Thank you .. The problem was with Cache. Earlier I tried with request.DATA but it didnt succeeded. Now it works.

Comment: `request.DATA` has been deprecated in favor of `request.data`

Comment: request.DATA print all the vairable but In want one vairable value hwo can i do this?

Comment: You should use request.data['username'] to get the value of a particular variable. Here you can replace any variable as you like.